lightweight chart for trading view is returning a black scale with nothing in it
even when setting the visibility of the left scale to true as well as the tick to true i still am unable to see the chart scale:
useEffect(() => {
        if (data.length && chartContainerRef.current) {
            const heightInPixels = window.innerHeight * 0.9;
            const chart = createChart(chartContainerRef.current, {
                width: chartContainerRef.current.offsetWidth,
                height: heightInPixels,
            });

            chart.applyOptions({
              crosshair:{
                mode:0
              },
              leftPriceScale: {
                visible: true,
                borderColor: "red",
                backgroundColor:"transparent",
                scaleMargins: {
                  bottom: 0.1,
                  top: 0.1
                },
                textColor: 'white',
                ticksVisible: true,
                entireTextOnly: true, 
                invertScale:false,
                
              },
              rightPriceScale:{
                visible:false
              },
             

            
             autoSize:true
            })

        

            const candleSeries = chart.addCandlestickSeries({
                upColor: '#4bffb5',
                downColor: '#ff4976',
                borderVisible: true,
                wickUpColor: '#4bffb5',
                wickDownColor: '#ff4976',
                priceScaleId:"left"

            });
            chart.timeScale().fitContent()
            chart.timeScale().resetTimeScale()

            candleSeries.setData(data);


            chart.timeScale().applyOptions({
                rightOffset: 12,
                barSpacing: 20,
                fixLeftEdge: true,
                ticksVisible:true,
                timeVisible:true
            });

            console.log('Chart options:', chart.options());


            return () => {
                chart.remove();
            };
        }
    }, [data]);

I then Console logged the chart options to see if the configurations were correct and here is the output:
{
    "width": 808,
    "height": 982.8000000000001,
    "autoSize": true,
    "layout": {
        "background": {
            "type": "solid",
            "color": "#FFFFFF"
        },
        "textColor": "#191919",
        "fontSize": 12,
        "fontFamily": "-apple-system, BlinkMacSystemFont, 'Trebuchet MS', Roboto, Ubuntu, sans-serif"
    },
    "crosshair": {
        "vertLine": {
            "color": "#9598A1",
            "width": 1,
            "style": 3,
            "visible": true,
            "labelVisible": true,
            "labelBackgroundColor": "#131722"
        },
        "horzLine": {
            "color": "#9598A1",
            "width": 1,
            "style": 3,
            "visible": true,
            "labelVisible": true,
            "labelBackgroundColor": "#131722"
        },
        "mode": 0
    },
    "grid": {
        "vertLines": {
            "color": "#D6DCDE",
            "style": 0,
            "visible": true
        },
        "horzLines": {
            "color": "#D6DCDE",
            "style": 0,
            "visible": true
        }
    },
    "overlayPriceScales": {
        "autoScale": true,
        "mode": 0,
        "invertScale": false,
        "alignLabels": true,
        "borderVisible": true,
        "borderColor": "#2B2B43",
        "entireTextOnly": false,
        "visible": false,
        "ticksVisible": false,
        "scaleMargins": {
            "bottom": 0.1,
            "top": 0.2
        },
        "minimumWidth": 0
    },
    "leftPriceScale": {
        "autoScale": true,
        "mode": 0,
        "invertScale": false,
        "alignLabels": true,
        "borderVisible": true,
        "borderColor": "red",
        "entireTextOnly": true,
        "visible": true,
        "ticksVisible": true,
        "scaleMargins": {
            "bottom": 0.1,
            "top": 0.1
        },
        "minimumWidth": 0,
        "backgroundColor": "transparent",
        "textColor": "white"
    },
    "rightPriceScale": {
        "autoScale": true,
        "mode": 0,
        "invertScale": false,
        "alignLabels": true,
        "borderVisible": true,
        "borderColor": "#2B2B43",
        "entireTextOnly": false,
        "visible": false,
        "ticksVisible": false,
        "scaleMargins": {
            "bottom": 0.1,
            "top": 0.2
        },
        "minimumWidth": 0
    },
    "timeScale": {
        "rightOffset": 12,
        "barSpacing": 20,
        "minBarSpacing": 0.5,
        "fixLeftEdge": true,
        "fixRightEdge": false,
        "lockVisibleTimeRangeOnResize": false,
        "rightBarStaysOnScroll": false,
        "borderVisible": true,
        "borderColor": "#2B2B43",
        "visible": true,
        "timeVisible": true,
        "secondsVisible": true,
        "shiftVisibleRangeOnNewBar": true,
        "allowShiftVisibleRangeOnWhitespaceReplacement": false,
        "ticksVisible": true,
        "uniformDistribution": false,
        "minimumHeight": 0,
        "allowBoldLabels": true
    },
    "watermark": {
        "color": "rgba(0, 0, 0, 0)",
        "visible": false,
        "fontSize": 48,
        "fontFamily": "-apple-system, BlinkMacSystemFont, 'Trebuchet MS', Roboto, Ubuntu, sans-serif",
        "fontStyle": "",
        "text": "",
        "horzAlign": "center",
        "vertAlign": "center"
    },
    "localization": {
        "locale": "en-GB",
        "dateFormat": "dd MMM 'yy"
    },
    "handleScroll": {
        "mouseWheel": true,
        "pressedMouseMove": true,
        "horzTouchDrag": true,
        "vertTouchDrag": true
    },
    "handleScale": {
        "axisPressedMouseMove": {
            "time": true,
            "price": true
        },
        "axisDoubleClickReset": {
            "time": true,
            "price": true
        },
        "mouseWheel": true,
        "pinch": true
    },
    "kineticScroll": {
        "mouse": false,
        "touch": true
    },
    "trackingMode": {
        "exitMode": 1
    }
}

The left price scale visibility is set to true and so are the ticks visible so why am i still getting a black scale.
Image this is the problem that i am facing
